# Error when trying to connect to flask via localhost

Tags: python, flask

I can across a script on github that send a Post request using flask.

I am trying run the script to establish a connection on my local host. But I get the below response

`The method is not allowed for the requested URL.`

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def index():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['file']
    # if user does not select file, browser also
    # submit a empty part without filename
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No selected file')
        return redirect(request.url)
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        warped = transform_file(file)
        return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', threaded=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method Not Allowed flask error 405](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689364/method-not-allowed-flask-error-405)

Comment: how do you connect to this code ?

Comment: if you want to connect from external computer then you have to use `host="0.0.0.0"` instead of `host='127.0.0.1'` because `127.0.0.1` doesn't accept requests from other computers - only from programs running on your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to have only a root  i.e "/" in your route.

Can you try with  a site, something like below:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

Comment: that does not seem to work for me. I have never used flask before, I just saw the script and I decided to try it out before replicating same using Django.

I get a `302 error` This page isn’t working

Comment: ok suppose if you are referring to the this https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/  then I think you have missed the return part in the end
`
return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''
`
can you include the return part in the code and see

Answer (score 0):

- First of all it's because you do not have a **GET** method for the route: **/** address but only POST and that's the reason why **Flask** displays that error.
- Definitely you should have a **return** statment at the end of function with either html code as @CoderRambo wrote in the comment or using **render_template** function pointing html file inside the templates folder.

Also if your going to use:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

you should add an if statment `if request.method == 'POST':` beforehand that part`if 'file' not in request.files:` - that would handle the post request and in **else** block have the **return** statment that will display the page onto which your going to enter data you'd like to post. As Flask's documention shows https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/:
[image: None]

Hope I helped.

Cheers