# How to retrieve from a Sqlite3 Database and compare it with User Inputs?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, flask-login

~~This Question is a continuation of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70446506/error-in-flask-and-python-sqlite3-integration).~~
I'm creating a basic Login Form and I am using **Flask** for serving my HTML Pages and **Sqlite3** Package in python for storage of usernames and passwords!

I started by creating an App Route!

I'm requesting the User Input from the form and then comparing it with the data I retrieve from my database named ***'Users.db'*** as follows:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    msg = ''
    
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
        # Create variables for easy access
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        #Connection Est.
        connection = sqlite3.connect("Users.db")

        #cursor
        USer_crsr = connection.cursor()

        user_cm = """SELECT username FROM accounts where"""
        user_cm_2 = """SELECT password FROM accounts"""

        USer_crsr.execute(user_cm)
        USer_crsr.execute(user_cm_2)

        USer_result = USer_crsr.fetchall()
        USer_result_2 = USer_crsr.fetchall()

        if username in USer_result and if password in USer_result_2:
            # Create session data, we can access this data in other routes
              session['loggedin'] = True
              session['id'] = USer_result['id']
              session['username'] = USer_result['username']
              # Redirect to home page
              return 'Logged in successfully!'
        else:
            # Account doesnt exist or username/password incorrect
            msg = 'Incorrect username/password!'
    return render_template("login.html", msg=msg)
```

(I know this code isn't correct!)

Any suggestions on what I can do to correctly retrieve my data from the database and comparing it to the User Input?

Comment: What if you used [flask-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead of reinventing the wheel? This module is specially designed for authentication management

Comment: I had tried using flask-login earlier but It isn't for advanced productional needs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after weeks of researching and reading articles, I finally got the article containing the answer to my Question and my Problem. So, I'm just gonna' post the article link here! **(It is an Article-Series, so it is recommended that you follow the whole series** **for more information, though reading the article alone also worked for me!)**

Also, please do read the Article wholly to understand all the components!

***Here's the link***:
**- https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/flask-development-part-4-database-configuration-648b11f708a5**

[Article Series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUxsX.png)    |||
[Github Repository](https://github.com/shawnhymers/FlaskApp/)